# how to set validations while creating columns in sharepoint programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am new to SharePoint and C#. Here is my code to create a text type column in my `list` :-

```
SPFieldText fldName = (SPFieldText)lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                                    SPFieldType.Text.ToString(), txtColumnName.Text);
                                    fldName.MaxLength = 200;
                                    lst.Fields.Add(fldName);
```

but i don't know **how to set validation and where in my code** that this field cannot be empty or something like that. Any work-around?

Answer (score 0):

You can create field from `SchemaXml`. For enforcing required, you can set `Required="TRUE"`. Have a look on the following `SchemaXml`, it will help more.

```
<Field Type="Text" 
         DisplayName="FirstName" 
         Required="TRUE" 
         EnforceUniqueValues="TRUE" 
         Indexed="TRUE" 
         MaxLength="255" 
        ID="{7cccfa31-ae19-4fa7-8a87-6cff7b01979e}" 
        SourceID="{18c38424-48dd-4ac5-b32e-f3cf7b5a3042}" 
        StaticName="FirstName" 
        Name="FirstName" 
        ColName="nvarchar4" 
        RowOrdinal="0" 
        Version="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property ValidationFormula of you Field as you would provide the Formula in the Field Settings, for example:

```
fldName.ValidationFormular = "="+txtColumnName.Text+"<> 'SomeText'";
```

(Prevents the value "SomeText" in your text column)

If only a value is required you can the the field to "Required":

```
fld.Required = true;
```

You should set the values before adding the field to the list.